# Drawing inside a subview of a UIView subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics, core-animation

I have more of a generic question. I have a custom class that subclasses `UIView`. I override '-drawRect' to draw points in a line which I successfully did. Now I declare another UIView object inside my class that I want to animate. It should be a white circle outline which I'd like to move with an animation and this is why I want it to be of `UIView` type. But how can I draw inside it? What if I have 3 other similar cases for example? So my point is, I want to keep all of the functionality inside the component's class and have custom drawing for one or more `UIView` subviews. I think I am missing something on conceptional level.

In ActionScript 3 I would do it so:

```
var first:MovieClip = new MovieClip();   
first.graphics...
......
var nTh:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
nTh.graphics...
```

This is what I want to achieve (as I said I've already made the drawing of the dots inside `-drawRect`, now I want to make the bigger circle which has to be animated later):
[image: example]

Comment: you can try putting the drawing code with in an animation block [UIView animationWithDuration:0.25 animations^{ // drawing code here}]; i don't know if this will work, but it might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is creating an UIView instance and setting its bounds and position in -initWithFrame:

```
//circleFrameSideSize will serve as the diameter of the circle
UIView *circle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, circleYPos, circleFrameSideSize, circleFrameSideSize)];
circle.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
circle.layer.borderWidth = 1;
//here we do the trick for making the circle with using layer's corner radius
circle.layer.cornerRadius = circleFrameSideSize/2;
[self addSubview:circle];
```